# Firebase phone login verify using Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I've managed to send an OTP using Firebase. The number also shows up under Authentication -> Users in Firebase Console. What I need to do is that if the number was verified, I want to navigate to next page. How do I do that?

One more thing is that when I enter the number and tap the button 'Verify', it just sends me an OTP message. The app doesn't prompt for the second TextFormField - "Enter OTP". Why is it doing that?

**main.dart**

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    // This widget is the root of your application.
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            home: Authenticate().handleAuth(),
        );
    }
}
```

**authenticate.dart**

```
class Authenticate {
  //to handle auth
  handleAuth() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return DashBoard();
        } else {
          return SignIn();
        }
      },
    );
  }

  //for signin
  signIn(AuthCredential authCreds) {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
  }

  //for manual otp entry
  signInViaOTP(smsCode, verId) {
    AuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId, smsCode: smsCode);
    signIn(authCredential);
  }

  signInViaOTPT(smsCode, verId) {
    AuthCredential authCredential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId, smsCode: smsCode);
    signIn(authCredential);
  }

  //for signout
  signout() {
    FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
}
```

**sign_in.dart**

```
class SignIn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SignInState createState() => _SignInState();
}

class _SignInState extends State<SignIn> {
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String phoneNo, verId, smsCode;
  bool codeSent = false;

  Future<void> verifyNum(num) async{
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verified = (AuthCredential authRes){
      Authenticate().signIn(authRes);
    };
    final PhoneVerificationFailed failed = (AuthException authExcep){

    };
    final PhoneCodeSent smsSent = (String verId, [int forceResend]){
      this.verId = verId;
      setState(() {
        this.codeSent = true;
      });
    };
    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoTimeOut = (String verId){
      this.verId = verId;
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
      phoneNumber: num,
      timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
      verificationCompleted: verified,
      verificationFailed: failed,
      codeSent: smsSent,
      codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoTimeOut
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Form(
        key: formKey,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter Phone Number"),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.phoneNo = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ),
            codeSent ? Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
              child: TextFormField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Enter OTP"),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  setState(() {
                    this.smsCode = val;
                  });
                },
              ),
            ) : Container(),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, right: 25.0),
              child: RaisedButton(
                child: Center(
                  child: codeSent ? Text("Login") : Text("Verify"),
                ),
                onPressed: (){
                  codeSent? Authenticate().signInViaOTP(smsCode, verId) : verifyNum(phoneNo);
                },
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> What I need to do is that if the number was verified, I want to navigate to next page. How do I do that?

You'd need to listen for a successful user authentication, then let the user proceed to the next page.

```dart
handlePhoneAuth(phoneNumber).then((User user) {
  if(user != null) {
    NavigateToNextPage();
  } else {
    // Display errors
  }
});
```

> when I enter the number and tap the button 'Verify', it just sends me an OTP message. The app doesn't prompt for the second TextFormField - "Enter OTP". Why is it doing that?

You need to build your own UI for handling the OTP sent to the user's phone number. Related to the above code snippet, here's an example on how you can handle phone authentication using `firebase_auth`.

```dart
Future<User> handlePhoneAuth(String userPhoneNumber) async {
  var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  auth.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: userPhoneNumber,
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int resendToken) async {
      // Update the UI - wait for the user to enter the SMS code
      String smsCode = 'xxxx';

      // Create a PhoneAuthCredential with the code
      PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: smsCode);

      // Sign the user in (or link) with the credential
      var userCredential = await auth.signInWithCredential(credential);
       return userCredential.user;
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException error) {
      debugPrint('Phone Auth failed $error');
      return null;
    },
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) {
      // only available for Android
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {
      return null;
    },
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Omatt for taking time to answer the question! The question is no longer relevant to me now but I hope your answer helps someone finding answer to a similar issue! ☺